# Confused about the Null Zero in C

Tags: c, null, char

Let's say you have:

```
char[5] = "March";
```

this won't work in C although:

```
char[0]='M'
char[1]='a'
char[2]='r'
char[3]='c'
char[4]='h'
char[5]='\0'
```

For some reason, I have to say to C that `char[6]="March"` and not `char [5]`.

Why is this? What goes into `char[6]`?

Comment: `char[5]` is an array containing 5 elements, not an array where 5 is the maximum valid index.

Answer (score 4):

First things first, `char` is not a valid variable in C, it's a *keyword*. You probably meant

```
char xyzzy[6];
```

or something similar, which would create a character array called `xyzzy`. But, once that's fixed up, *nothing* goes into `xyyzy[6]`. The statement `char xyzzy[6];` means an array of *six* characters, the indexes of which are `0` through `5` inclusive: `{0,1,2,3,4,5}`, that's six elements.

In any case, unless you *need* the array to be bigger, you're usually better off letting the compiler choose the size with:

```
char xyzzy[] = "March";
```

Comment: Thing is, I seem to be confusing the maximum valid index and the number of elements. char m[5] >>> does this mean that it has 5 elements (with indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4) or the maximum valid index is 5 (in that case it would have 6 elements, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)?

Comment: @daremarkovic, the former. Five elements, indexes 0 through 4 inclusive.

Comment: The number in the `[]` is the number of elements. i.e. 5 in your case.

Answer (score 1):

**A string literal, `"March"` in this case, has an implicit null terminator so a `char[]` array requires `6` elements to store it.** To quote the relevant points from the section *6.4.5 String literals* of the C99 standard:

> A character string literal is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in
>   double-quotes, as in "xyz".
>
> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte
>   character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.

In both cases the code is overrunning the end of the array. The code currently has undefined behaviour.

Change to:

```
char a[6] = "March";
```

The second code snippet accesses beyond the end of the array as indexes run from `0` to `N - 1`, where `N` is the number of elements in the array. For an array `char a[5];` the valid index are `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`.

Comment: I know that, the question was why.

Comment: Because you may have strings allocated at runtime(`char *`) thus you cannot always infer the length of these string using only `sizeof`. To manage strings you have to: keep the length in some place or use a terminator character. The C standard uses the terminator character.

Comment: Say we had char m[5] = "March". It seems I'm confusing [5] - which is the number of elements vs. the maximum valid index. Does m[5] means that the number of elements is 5 or the maximum valid index is 5(so the maximum num. of characters is 6, that is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) or the

Comment: `char a[n]` means an array of n "slots". So the maximum index is `n-1`.

Comment: @daremarkovic, I have mentioned the array indexing in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The null terminator \0 goes in the last slot.
It is there because otherwise there would be no way to check the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 elements if you count from 0 to 5 included.

So you must declare a `char[6]` in order to have `str[0]` to `str[5]`.

Answer (score 0):

`char [5]` means, you have memory for 5x sizeof(char). 0-5 are six times sizeof(char): 0 first, 1 second, 2 third, 3 fourth, 4 fifth, 5 sixth. So you need a segment with 6 times sizeof(char): `char [6]`. The first cell, zero, consumes space, too.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing goes into char[6], but you still need a char[] of size 6 to hold the 6 characters including the null-terminator byte. They will go into char[0] through char[5]. char[6] remains undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
char array[n]
```

means an n elements long array, not an array whose last index is `n`. Because in C, arrays are zero-based, it means that the last valid index of an n-element array is `n - 1`. Since there's a zero terminator for a string, and "March" is 5 letters, that's a total of 6 characters, so you have to write `char str[6] = "March";`. If that's confusing for now, don't include the length of the array; for initialized arrays, the compiler will automagically fill it in, so you can write `char str[] = "March";` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Char` is a keyword not a variable name, so don't use it as one.

Array indexing: that is counting the number of characters in an array begining from 0, i.e a[0].

Suppose there are 5 characters in the array (for eg: tiger) then a[0] = 't' and a[4] = 'r' and all the string literals in this case an array of characters ends in a '\0' i.e a EOF

character. So to store an array of n characters use a[n] compiler will add '\0' at the end of that array.